# Sort table by a column and set other column to sequential value to persist ordering

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-1.4

So I'm not sure whether to pose this as a Django or SQL question however I have the following model:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    taken_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, db_column="album_id", related_name='pictures')
```

I may have a subset of Picture records numbering in the thousands, and I'll need to sort them by `taken_date` and persist the order by setting the `weight` value.

For instance in Django:

```
pictures = Picture.objects.filter(album_id=5).order_by('taken_date')
for weight, picture in enumerate(list(pictures)):
    picture.weight = weight
    picture.save()
```

Now for 1000s of records as I'm expecting to have, this could take way too long. Is there a more efficient way of performing this task? I'm assuming I might need to resort to SQL as I've recently come to learn Django's not necessarily "there yet" in terms of database bulk operations.

Comment: Is the sample code setting weight to its current value? I don't see where anything is actually being updated, or am I missing something?

Comment: In both the original queryset, and the SQL, I'm creating a `weight` value per row which is a sequential number and is not taken from the original record at all, and then applying that weight value to `picture.weight`.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to your own question. That makes it clearer for others that will view this question in the future, and allows your answer to be voted up/down and compared to other answers that may be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I put together the following in MySQL which works fine, however I'm gonna guess there's no way to simulate this using Django ORM?

```
UPDATE picture p
JOIN (SELECT @inc := @inc + 1 AS new_weight, id 
FROM (SELECT @inc := 0) temp, picture 
WHERE album_id = 5 
ORDER BY taken_date) pw
ON p.id = pw.id
SET p.weight = pw.new_weight;
```

I'll leave the question open for a while just in case there's some awesome solution or app that solves this, however the above query for ~6000 records takes 0.11s.

**NOTE** that the above query will generate warnings in MySQL if you have the following setting in MySQL:

```
binlog_format=statement
```

In order to fix this, you must change the `binlog_format` setting to either `mixed` or `row`. `mixed` is probably better as it means you'll still use `statement` for everything except in cases where `row` is required to avoid a warning like the above.

Comment: This seems to run a bit faster:
UPDATE page AS m_change RIGHT JOIN (select @i:=@i+10 as rank, m.id as id from page as m, (SELECT @i:=0) as r where app='somefilter' order by m.sequence asc) AS m_rank ON m_change.id = m_rank.id set sequence=rank;